# Access data from other instance

Tags: sql-server-2012

Friends,
Please let me know how to get the data from other local instance in sql server 2012.

I have 2 instance in my local server. I want get data from the table that staored in other instance.

Server 1 : ICS2012\ICS2012  - Default Instance
Server 2: ICSDBONLINE\NEWINSTANCE_1 - Newly created

Table named "Black_List" stored in Default Instance(ICS2012), how to access same table in NEWINSTANCE_1.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The following describes in general how to connect to other data sources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175807(v=sql.105).aspx

I'm not sure if there is any shortcut to doing this as the external data source is SQL Server however.